# How to send cron output to an email?

Tags: email, cron

I've set up a cron on my server as :

0 */1 * * * /usr/bin/curl http://example.com/function_name > /dev/null

Currently the output is not stored anywhere. The cron just outputs a boolean value whether the job was successful or not.

Now the problem is that the client is always in doubt whether the cron ran or not, so I just want to email the cron output to his email.

How to send the cron output to email ??

Answer (score 0):

You can cron a php file that runs the desired functions and then also runs a [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function afterwards to send the email. This works great for reporting on the success of the cron scheduled functions